# Matrix elements of vector current in $\pi^-$ decay

Tags: parity, matrix-elements, pions

In positive pion decay $\pi^- \rightarrow \mu^- + \overline{\nu}_\mu$, the matrix element contains the following factor:

$$<0|\overline{u}(0)\gamma^\mu d(0)|\pi^-(p)>$$

On the book by Nachtmann, "Elementary particle physics", it is said (page 384) that since the pion is a pseudoscalar meson the first expression must transform as a "pseudoscalar". I assume "pseudoscalar" is a typo, and the author intended "pseudovector" or "axial-vector". But how to show these properties?

My attempt:
I have to show that the matrix element is an axial-vector. A parity transformation should give (please, correct if I'm wrong):

$$<0|\overline{u}(0)\gamma^\mu d(0)|\pi^-(p)> \quad\rightarrow \\-<0| \overline{u}(0)\gamma_\mu d(0)|\pi^-(p)>$$

In other terms, parity changes the sign of the spatial components
If I apply a parity transformation to the first matrix element, which is represented by the operator $U(P)$:

$$<0|\overline{u}(0)\gamma^\mu d(0)|\pi^-(p)> \quad\rightarrow \\<0|U(P)^+ \overline{u}(0)\gamma^\mu d(0)U(P)|\pi^-(p)> \quad=\\ -<0| \overline{u}(0)\gamma^\mu d(0)|\pi^-(p')>$$

where $p'=(p^0,-\vec{p})$. Then I'm stuck. How to correctly apply a parity transformation to the matrix element and bring down the lorentz index $\mu$?

Comment: A vector and a pseudoscalar have negative parity, an even number of minus signs.

Comment: Thank to your comment I realized that I was considering a wrong transformation for an axial 4-vector. 
Anyway the problem remains. How to apply correctly a parity transformation to the matrix element?